# Determine format of data by its syntax

Tags: serialization, format, deserialization, dataformat

I have a data represented in unknown to me format. It was originally in base64, after decoding the data it now looks like that:

```
a:119:{i:0;a:19:{s:6:"some_value";s:36:"some_value";s:9:"some_value";s:13:"some_value";s:13:"some_value";s:10:"some_value";s:9:"some_value";s:3:"some_value";s:7:"some_value";s:10:"some_value";s:11:"some_value";N;s:12:"some_value";N;s:8:"some_value";s:10:"2019-03-02";s:8:"some_value";s:16:"some_value";s:8:"some_value";s:3:"some_value"...
```

I need to parse it, but I don't know what format it is. The data contains some string values, which are certainly used for displaying a table in a web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself. Wikipedia contains the [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats) of all (or maybe most) serialization formats. This format is the result of [serialize](http://php.net/serialize) function in PHP.